# What does this try and catch method do?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

```
try 
{
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I understand what the first part is doing. But what is the catch part waiting for? Like what needs to happen to execute this part.

Comment: BTW that's most probably the wrong way to handle `InterruptedException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every piece of code is run by a "thread". You can think of that as a little virtual processor dedicated to running that particular piece of code.

By calling the `Thread.sleep()` method, you put this thread in the `WAITING` state for a certain amount of time. While `WAITING`, the thread cannot do anything, and in particular, it cannot "hear" calls from other threads.

The only way to wake up the thread and having it run its code again, is to sent it an interruption, which is a very strong signal. This is done by calling the `interrupt()` method of this thread, from another thread.

When waked up, the thread goes to the `RUNNING` state again, but to signal the developer that it was waked up earlier than expected, it throws an [`InterruptedException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html), which is a checked exception. This is why you have to catch it and deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

The sleep method halts execution of the current thread, in your case 5000 milliseconds (5 seconds). This method however throws InterruptedException which has to be caught.

Answer (score 1):

Because the [Thread#sleep()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) method is defined to throw an `InterruptedException` under some circumstances, the developer should take care of it when this exact exception occurs. This is why the `catch` block is needed - to hold the logic which handles the `InterruptedException`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class InterruptedException
extends Exception
```

> Thrown when a thread is waiting, sleeping, or otherwise occupied, and
>   the thread is interrupted, either before or during the activity.
>   Occasionally a method may wish to test whether the current thread has
>   been interrupted, and if so, to immediately throw this exception.

Best Explanation is Given ╠══ [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)

Answer (score 1):

You thread is going to sleep for 5 seconds.

If another thread tries to wake this thread up (Interrupt). It will end up in the exception block and your stacktrace will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

If `InterruptedException` throws(Thread interruption may cause this) from `try` block that will catch by `catch` block and as you define in the catch block,it will print the `Exception` stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

If the **Thread** is interrupted then it will throw the exception and it will be catched in the `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

This is relevant to [multithreaded applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).When you have reference to an object of a class that either `implements Runnable` or `extends Thread`, and inside that object, a `Thread.sleep(i)` method has been idling the process, you can call `reference.interupt()` on that reference and it will trigger the `InterruptedException`. Here's an example:

In the below code, the `Scratch` class's `run` method goes to sleep for 60000 ms (or 1 minute) and prints "I've been interrupted" if it receives an `InterruptedExection`. The way the code is written, it will not receive this exception and will sleep the entire time. But run it a second time with the line `//scratch.interrupt();` uncommented and see what happens.

```
package scratch;
/**
 *
 * @author bstidham
 */
public class Scratch extends Thread {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello from a thread!");
        System.out.println("Going to sleep for 1 minute...");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("I've been interrupted!");
        }
        System.out.println("Awake now");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scratch scratch = new Scratch();
        scratch.start();
        //scratch.interrupt();
    }
}
```